# html form unable to submit and back to the same page

Tags: php, html

I have this form below which is use to submit to a payment gateway. Problem is that once I click on the button, it won't go to 3rd party payment page. However, if I click second time, then it only go through? Why is that so?

```
<form method="post" action="" name="payment">
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>


function PAYMENT_FORM($price, $username, $useremail, $usercontact, $desc, $desc2){
      //Content of the function 
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo PAYMENT_FORM($cart->total, $user['firstname']." ".$user['lastname'], $user['email'], $user['telephone'], $desc, $desc2);
}
```

Comment: Your problem is not too clear. Give some more description. Provide proper code. Try to use this if your are submitting to same page `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`

Comment: Your FORM contains no elements other than the submit button. If I had to take a guess, your FORM needs to load via a POST request rather than a GET request, which is the difference from the first submit and the second submit.